# Как можно выводить значения из массива по таймеру?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть масив который содержыт оприделенное количество элементов(строк), который он должен выводить по одному элементу каждые 5 секунд по таймеру. Загвоздка в том, что в массиве элементов может быть разное количество ...

Пример массива:

```
var mass = ["elem_1", "elem_2, "elem_3"];
```

Как можно решыть такую проблемму ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var arr = ['elem_1', 'elem_2', 'elem_3'],
    i = 0,
    timerID;

timerID = setTimeout(function tick () {
    if (i < arr.length) {
        console.log(mass[i]);
        i++;
        timerID = setTimeout(tick, 5000);
    }

}, 5000);
```